# What is a good way to handle GridControl Row Selection events in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridcontrol

So in a GridControl, the user selects which session he wants to view and then press on a "See Gallery" which will take the application to a "next" View - Gallery, then another GridControl to select which Image in that gallery and press "See Images" to go and so on.

I am trying to get rid of all "Buttons" and let the user "row selection" within the grid itself act as an event handler to the next View (Session->Gallery->Image->.. etc). This will save one step on every view "Selecting instead of selecting + clicking"

I used the property `sessionGrid.SelectedItemChanged` and created its event handler as follows and put the same event handler of the OnClick Gallery Button:

```
    private void sessionGrid_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SeeGalleryClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }
```

This worked exactly how I wanted. On Grid-Row selection, the application switches to the next view for that specific row. However, if the user go back and then selects the same row, it will not go to the next view since "Selected Item did not change".

If I can I use something like this:

```
sessionsUserControl.sessionGrid.SelectedItemChanged = ??;
```

to reset the "selection" in a grid it will be awesome. But is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed using the TouchDown/MouseDown event handler as follows:

```
        private void sessionGrid_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        GalleryButtonClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }
```

now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use databinding. bind SelectedItem/SelectedIndex  property to a property in codebehind.
Whenever User selects a row,you will get notified.
you can select a different row  by setting a different value to this property.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I fixed it using the TouchDown event handler on the Grid itself